# Cut (crop) some text in a string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a string with 3 block parameters (words, digits, slashes) and i need to separate it and print only last block parameters. I do this:

```
<?php
$howmuch="17шт / 119ml / 255грн";
echo preg_replace("/(\\d\\w\\ / )(\\d\\w\\ / )(\\d\\w\\ / )$/i", "$3", $howmuch);
?>
```

I need to print only 255грн, but my script do nothing. Please help me to fix a problem. Thank you to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is fixed, you may get the value without any regex using

```
explode(" / ", $howmuch)[2]
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/vAs0wf). It will split the string with `space-/-space` and get you the third element of the resulting array.

Alternatively, you may *extract* a number with `грн` after it using a `preg_match` operation (this approach lets you find the match regardless of how many `/` there are before or after the match):

```
$howmuch="17шт / 119ml / 255грн";
if (preg_match("/\d+\s*грн/ui", $howmuch, $results)) {
    echo $results[0];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/kn4XuU).

If the value can contain a fractional part, you may use `"/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*грн/ui"` where `(?:[.,]\d+)?` matches an optional sequence of a `.` or `,` followed with 1+ digits.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it simple and understandable, for instance, like this:

```
$howMuch = '17шт / 119ml / 255грн';
$blocks  = explode('/',$howMuch);
echo $blocks[2];
```

This doesn't need much explaining, or working out why it does what it does.

Answer (score 1):

**All regex free options:**

```
echo explode('/', $howMuch)[2];
```

*if you need to ensure string has three sections*

```
if (substr_count($howmuch, '/') > 1) {
    echo explode('/', $howMuch)[2];
}
```

*if you are on a php version prior to 5.4*

```
$chunks = explode('/', $howMuch);
echo $chunks[2];
```